# How to interpret and control XGBRegressor tree model selected parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I'm using scikit-learn to make predictions on a continuous variable

**data :**

- features : `geneName, diseaseName, drugName, EI, EL, DPI, DSI, pLI`
- column to predict : `Decision`

**data type :** 
I'm using Frequency-based encoding to transform the categorical columns `geneName, diseaseName, drugName` into numerical values, (each column have more than +100 category)
the column `EL` have 6 categories and I'm using Label encoding to map it into numerical values

**Training the model :** 
I'm training the model using these hyperparameters:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgbr=xgb.XGBRegressor(
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    max_depth=15,
    n_estimators=1000,
    reg_alpha=1.1,
    reg_lambda=1.3,
    subsample=0.7)
xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

**Results:**
Training the model gives to following results for these metrics :

```
Score : 0.9855
Mean cross-validation score: 0.97
MSE: 0.00035
RMSE: 0.01874
```

The cross validation calculated as follows:

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
kf_cv_scores = cross_val_score(xgbr, x_train, y_train, cv=kfold )
```

and gave:

```
K-fold CV average score: 0.97
```

Here is the model tree printed image : [tree model image](https://svgshare.com/i/U1B.svg)

**My Questions:**

1. printing the tree model, I see that many tree leaf nodes have value -0. Why?
2. how can I control the selection parameters used in the tree? because it looks like xgboost is selecting multiple splits of the same variable.
3. What are your thoughts about these predictions?

Comment: 1) the image you have linked to asks for download (not cool) 2) you cannot 3) too vague & opinion-based. Plus, it is not clear what you mean by "Accuracy" here, since this is a regression problem where accuracy is meaningless.

Comment: @desertnaut sorry for the link, the image size is too large and I wanted to preserve its 
quality, I updated my question. by the training accuracy I mean the score of the model (correct me if I'm wrong) the score is calculated like : `xgbr.score(x_train, y_train)`